# Unable to launch rattle - "Memory not mapped"

Tags: rstudio, rattle

I'm trying to launch rattle on my R console, but whenever I run the `rattle` command, my R console crashes with a "memory not mapped" error message. Could anyone advise me on what could have gone wrong and how do I resolve this issue?

I am running MacOS Version 10.14.5 and I have installed cairoDevice_2.26.tar.gz and RGtk2_2.20.36.tgz following the instruction posted on this GitHub page (https://gist.github.com/sebkopf/9405675)

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMalE.jpg)